# Switching from multiple pages being loaded into div to all divs being stored on one page

Tags: php

Hi everyone I'm currently using a basic div framework that loads data from other pages into a div. But now I want to move towards a solution where all the div content is stored and accessed on one **HTML** page. I've been thinking about using jQuery tabs. How would I go about implementing this solution.

Here is the code I'm currently using below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
  $page=$_GET['page'];
}else{
  $page='home';
}
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  A Basic Div Framework
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'nav-button-mark';}else{echo 'nav-button';} ?>"><a href='?page=home'>首页 home</a></div>
    <div class="<?php if($page=='page1'){echo 'nav-button-mark';}else{echo 'nav-button';} ?>"><a href='?page=page1'>网页一 page 1</a></div>
    <div class="<?php if($page=='page2'){echo 'nav-button-mark';}else{echo 'nav-button';} ?>"><a href='?page=page2'>网页二 page 2</a></div>
    <div class="<?php if($page=='page3'){echo 'nav-button-mark';}else{echo 'nav-button';} ?>"><a href='?page=page3'>网页三 page 3</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  <?php
  switch($page){
  case 'home':
    echo '<h1>Home Page Content</h1>';
    echo '<h3>$_GET</h3><pre>';print_r($_GET);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_POST</h3><pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_SESSION</h3><pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
    break;
  case 'page1':
    echo '<h1>Page 1 Content</h1>';
    echo '<h3>$_GET</h3><pre>';print_r($_GET);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_POST</h3><pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_SESSION</h3><pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
    break;
  case 'page2':
    echo '<h1>Page 2 Content</h1>';
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="?page=page3" />
    <input type='text' size='40' name='user-input' />
    <input type='submit' name='mysubmit' />
    </form>
    <?php
    echo '<h3>$_GET</h3><pre>';print_r($_GET);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_POST</h3><pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_SESSION</h3><pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
    break;
  case 'page3':
    if(isset($_POST['mysubmit'])){
      $_SESSION['user-input']=$_POST['user-input'];}
    echo '<h1>Page 3 Content</h1>';
    echo '<h3>$_GET</h3><pre>';print_r($_GET);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_POST</h3><pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<h3>$_SESSION</h3><pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
    break;
  default:
    echo '<h1>Error: Unknown Page!!</h1>';
    break;
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do is load all your "pages" into one html document and use javascript to allow users to click menu links to display the pages as though they might be separate html documents.

If each "page" has minimal content then there is justification to load it all into one document to give the users instant satisfaction instead of clicking and waiting... I have used this technique on various websites. In all cases, I used a combination of CSS and javascript to help me pull it off... I don't know if a jquery tab is the right solution - perhaps it is but i find large libraries to be the shotgun approach to getting things done - perhaps you might agree from the tight solution i will offer below:

1. Every "page" should have it's own div but, ideally, share the same class.
2. The class you define should hide those div's using css's display:none directive
3. Your main page can have an inline style directive display:block to over-ride the class directive which hides it
4. Each "page", excluding the main page, should have their id set to a short word or Pascal-cased short phrase
5. Your anchor tags to these "pages" should share a class so that a javascript routine can find them and operate on them
6. Also, these anchor tags should have href set with fragment identifiers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) that point to the appropriate "pages", ie. if you have a "page" with an id set to "AboutUs", the corresponding anchor might look like this: < a href="#AboutUs" >About Us< /a >. You will want to use fragment identifiers in your urls so that google and other search engines can process this notion of "pages" within your html document. Also, people will be able to externally link to these pages and you just need a bit of javascript to make it all work (next step).
7. Ok, we need some javascript so that when a user clicks an external link to one of your pages then it will display. It will need to be run onload of the document... you can put it into body.onload:

   ```
   // the hash has the hash mark which we can parse away using String.substr()
   var hash = document.location.hash.substr(1);
   // now to call a function to display the desired page
   ShowPage(hash);
   ```
8. Don't forget, we'll need the function to show the desired page:

   ```
   function ShowPage(hash) {
   // iterate the pages and show/hide
   var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
   for (var p in pages) {

       if (pages[p].id == hash) pages[p].style.display = block;
       else pages[p].style.display = none;
   }
   ```

Note: Older browsers don't support document.getElementsByClassName ... there are some great cross-browser techniques to add the function when not supported. Libraries like jQuery also ensure the functionality for all browsers - again, I'm not a fan of shotgun approaches and i would just overload the document dom node with my own getElementsByClassName function if i found it missing.

More fun stuff: if you want to get fancy with CSS3, instead of using display:block|none to show|hide pages, you could set pages to be absolutely positioned and transparent. With CSS3 transitions, you can animate the change between opaque to transparent for a fade-in effect on the user's click of a link... or, if you like modal windows, you can use a library like nyromodal (or script something tighter to your needs by yourself which is my preference)

A fully functioning example can be found at: http://reinpetersen.com/examples/intlnk/#PageThree

Comment: Yes but I want to use jQuery. Is this possible with jQuery? All of the pages have minimal content.

Comment: absolutely you can use jQuery - it would solve the problem of getElementsByTagName reaching older browsers. it would also provide some scripting shortcuts. if you are using jQuery for other scripts on the page then there is more justification for including a large library into the page. i'm a purist from the early days when we had to use 28.8k and 33.6k baud modems so you had to be really prudent about bandwidth - i can't seem to shake that... jQuery (minimized) is still pretty small - and it is a great library...

Comment: have a look again at item 6 - i made a small edit to allow the anchor tag sample to be displayed ... it was getting stripped out on the server...

Comment: Can I please see an example on jsFiddle if possible?

Comment: I could write the code for you but I wouldn't use jQuery. To be honest, I don't really support javascript libraries because I feel they are a waste of bandwidth and memory. It is a different story with compiled code because you can use libraries and the compiler strips away only what is necessary when it resolves to machine code. But with javascript, we are, essentially, the compilers. It is up to us to reduce code for bandwidth and memory footprint's sake. Also, I don't like how they have stepped on the dollar sign which I think would be better reserved to indicate protected functions.

Comment: I have a feeling this might flame some ardent jQuery supporters - not my intention. I just want to explain why I don't want to write examples using jQuery. But I would be happy to write some tight javascript to demonstrate the technique for you if you like :)

Comment: Yes please! Would really appreciate that!

Comment: hmm, i have a completely functioning sample with everything embedded in an html file but i don't see any way to post it here without creating a new answer and spending hours formatting it to display correctly... how can i post this sample file for you?

Comment: My email address is theshizy@hotmail.co.uk